# Scala Parser Combinators: "or" and different cases

Tags: java, scala, switch-statement, parser-combinators

I'm writing a `Parser` in `Scala` which should parse following `Grammar`:

```
my_parser = (id | "(" expr ")" ) "(" [ { expr "," } expr ] ")"
```

**My Parser Class**:

```
class ExpParser extends JavaTokenParsers {

  def expr: Parser[Expression] = my_parser | id

  [...]    

  private def my_parser : Parser[MyParser] = (id | "(" ~> expr ~ ")") ~ "(" ~ repsep(expr, ",") <~ ")" ^^ {
    case i ~ _ ~ le => MyParser(i, le)               //Error at Constructor first parameter: i
    case  expr ~ _ ~ _ ~ le => MyParser( expr, le)   //Error at Constructor first parameter: expr
  }

  [...]
}

object ParseProgram extends ExpParser {
  def parse(s: String): ParseResult[Expression] = {
    parseAll(expr, s)
  }
}
```

**My Case Class:**

```
sealed trait Expression
[...]
case class MyParser(e: Expression, l : List[Expression]) extends Expression
case class Id(i: String) extends Expression
[...]
```

In the `case-statements` i get following error messages:

*First Case* at the first `Parameter`of my `MyParser(i, le)` `constructor`: **i**

> Type mismatch, expected: Expression, actual: Product with Serializable

and

*Second Case:* at the first `Parameter`of my `MyParser(expr, le)` `constructor`: **expr**

> Type mismatch, expected: Expression, actual: Any

How can i differ between

- `id` and a List of `Expressions` and
- `Expression` and a List of `Expressions`

Comment: Is `my_parser = Parser[MyParser]` a typo or? Usually when you get `expected: Expression, actual: Product with Serializable` you should specify the type that you expect, compiler gave up... Also, I would recommend you to use [Fastparse](http://www.lihaoyi.com/fastparse/), it's awesome! :) Here are some [examples](https://github.com/sake92/nand2tetris/blob/master/projects/10/Compiler/src/main/scala/ba/sake/nand2tetris/compiler/Parser.scala#L224).

Comment: `MyParser` is a `case class` which wants a `Expression` and  a `List of Expressions` as arguments. And since `id` extends `Expression` i thought it would be enough but it apparently isn't.

Comment: `Fastparse` would be nice but i'm not allowed to use it